# Back button inside UISplitViewController disappears after rotate

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

i have an iOS app structured more or less like this:

```
UISplitViewController
-> (Master View) UITableViewController
-> (Detail View) UITabBarController
   -> Tab 1
      -> UINavigationController
         -> ViewController 1, ViewController 2
```

When I'm in "ViewController 2" I have the back button, in the navigation bar, for return to "ViewController 1" BUT, when i rotate the iPad (for example from portrait to landscape) the "Back" button disappears, and it never reappear back.

What could be the cause? I'm using xCode 8.2 and the iPad have iOS 8.1.

**SOME OTHER DETAILS:**

1. The Button is always hidden when I start the app from landscape.
2. The Storyboard is instantiated manually in AppDelegate.

Comment: You will have delegate methods to hide and show UIBarbuttonitem in your code. When both master and detail are on the screen in the landscape mode you will be hiding the button. Check or share some code in the question.

Comment: The control of the left BarButtonItem is leaved as it is, no delegate methods are implemented.